# How to combine django datefield and timefield

Tags: python, django

I have tried this query:

```
start_date = DateField()
strt_time = TimeField()
obj=model.objects.annotate(
                datetimeobj=ExpressionWrapper(F('start_date') + F('strt_time'), output_field=DateTimeField()
```

It gives following error:

> AttributeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'

I have also tried this solution:

```
data=model.objects.annotate(datetime=datetime.combine('start_date','start_time'))
```

It gives error:

> TypeError: combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not str

Thank you..

Comment: Why not make a `DateTimeField`? By using a `DateField()` you "introduce" problems that are already solved with a specific field.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your code `data=model.objects.annotate(datetime=datetime.combine('start_date','start_time'))` as  you are passing strings to the `combine()` method which expects date and time.

To merge date and time you are using datetime.combine() whose syntax is

`datetime.combine(date, time)`

So you have to do as:

```
data=model.objects.annotate(datetime=datetime.combine(start_date,start_time))
```

Comment: I tried with above solution, It gives NameError: name 'start_date' is not defined

Comment: i think you have misspelled start_date bcoz in your code some where you have mentioned `strt_date` and in some other places you mentioned `start_date`